# International law regarding human trafficing

Tags: united-states, international, canada, human-trafficking

What lawyers can handle a case that crosses borders and involves debt bondage human trafficking plus other crimes for victims of these crimes that take place in and between Canada and the U.S.?

Comment: Are you contemplating a civil case or a criminal case?  If criminal, call the police in the jurisdiction where the trafficking victim is currently located.

Comment: Hi there are 2 aspects to the case the civil which is in British Columbia canada and the criminal which was sent to Washington, D.C.

Comment: I am the victim and I was gathering evidence while working for the company it is debt bondage human trafficking

Comment: I was wearing a digital wire and have crime on tape

Comment: Are the police involved?

Comment: There was no need for this question be closed; the question basically inquiring about what field of practice a narrower type of legal matter falls in or lawyers specializing in what field cover a certain issue is on topic on law.SE; I voted to reopen, and invite others to do the same.

Comment: reading the comment on Oct 6 2016 at 16:07, this is in the contrary a request for legal advice.

Comment: This is **NOT**  a request for specific legal advice as law.se uses that term. It is asking about the needed expertise of a lawyer to handle a particular kind of case. That is specifically on-topic here "dealing with legal professionals". I urge others to vote to reopen this.

Comment: If it's asking about the area of expertise it needs more details.  It talks about "crimes" so presumably it would be a defense lawyer since only government prosecutors can bring criminal charges.  If not defense then what's the question?

Comment: @feetwet The disheartening reality of trafficking cases is that they — the more sophisticated and less direct they are — the exponentially more difficult they get, and government attorneys don't typically like to actually prosecute them. That's the sad fact. See the absolute queen of the field, Martina Vandenberg, who founded and presides the Human Trafficking Legal Center which basically trains all the trafficking attorneys of the nation, talk about it here: https://youtu.be/kQYleV0VTU0 As she explains, in most cases the only justice, if any, those trafficked get today is in civil court; […]

Comment: […] the vast majority of those trafficked, are immigrants, and more often than not, are "undocumented" refugees and asylum seekers (even if they have no clue they are) and therefore, T-visa and/or U-visa specializing attorneys are also within the scope. Within the civil branch, there are attorneys specializing in pursuing damages for victims of human trafficking and even if the causes of actions often overlap with other areas, this bread of attorney is, in fact, very specialized; some causes of action are exclusively trafficking related (18 U.S.C. § 1595; Title VII etc.) […]

Comment: […], some have special trafficking forms (RICO). The question begs for a comprehensive answer, I'm already drafting my third comment.